# Redux abstraction level in selectors with typescript

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, redux

this is the default implementation of redux with typescript using the connect method

```
import { connect, ConnectedProps } from 'react-redux'
    
    interface RootState {
      isOn: boolean
    }
    
    const mapState = (state: RootState) => ({
      isOn: state.isOn,
    })
    
    const mapDispatch = {
      toggleOn: () => ({ type: 'TOGGLE_IS_ON' }),
    }
    
    const connector = connect(mapState, mapDispatch)
    
    // The inferred type will look like:
    // {isOn: boolean, toggleOn: () => void}
    type PropsFromRedux = ConnectedProps<typeof connector>
```

I want to have reusable selectors from different components I have my selectors as functions seperately rather than in an object mapState like in the example.

So my selectors in a simplified version would be something like:

selectors.js:

```
const selector1 = (state) => state.attr1;
const selector2 = (state) => state.attr2;
const selector3 = (state) => state.attr3;
```

I want to create a function that accepts an object
eg

```
import {selector1,selector2} from '../../selectors';    
const selectors = {
    attr1:selector1,
    attr3:selector3,
}
```

pass it through a wrapper function and then that function to generate the mapState
I have successfully done that

```
const mapStateToProps = (selectors: Selectors) => {
  return Object.keys(selectors).reduce((acc, selectorKey) => {
    acc[selectorKey] = selectors[selectorKey](state);
    return acc;
  }, {});
};
```

so I can use it like this `const connector =connect(mapStateToProps(selectors),actions)`
but the generated output doesn't have any types. Is this feasible?

Redux suggests to retrieve the props from  `type PropsFromRedux = ConnectedProps<typeof connector>` but in my case only the types of actions appear

Answer (score 1):

Per our docs, you should *avoid* using `connect` for any new code today.  Instead, [you should use the React-Redux hooks API (`useSelector` and `useDispatch`)](https://react-redux.js.org/api/hooks).

One of the major reasons for this is that the hooks are *much* easier to use with TypeScript.

See [our guidelines for setting up "pre-typed" hooks for use in your app code](https://redux.js.org/tutorials/typescript-quick-start#define-typed-hooks).